# Phpmailer not sending email on same domain

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a website and there is a contact form. My code below :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

if (!$mail->addAddress('email@domain.com','email')) {
  die('Invalid email address');
}
$mail->isSMTP();
//$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$text = 'A mail...';
$mail->MsgHTML($text);
$mail->SetFrom($email);
//$mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);

if ($mail->Send()){
```

If user enter his/her mail adress like 'address@gmail.com' or 'add@hotmail.com', it sends email to that address.But if I enter my@mydomain.com, it says message send, but mail is not arrived. I'm searching for 2 days but can not found proper solution. I did also try this:

I wroted $mail->addAddress('mybackupmail@gmail.com','email'), and I forwarded the incoming mail to mybackupmail@gmail.com to 'mydomain@domain.com'. It is also not sending. I almost tried everything. My mx records like below:

[image]

Should I change these settings or not? Or the problem with sth else?

I would very appreciate any help.

Thanks for interest,

Comment: yilmaz check mail server's log

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a cpanel hosting with godaddy?  I dunno if this is "cpanel everywhere", or just at godaddy, but go into your cpanel and look for a thing called "MX Entry" then change it from local to remote.  Local tells the server "we are the mail engine for this domain that we have here in this cpanel", and remote tells it "the email for this domain is handled outside of cpanel" ... your MX records tell me you're using workspace email, thus you need MX Entry to remote :)

Comment: I spend almost 9 hours to get this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Function sample send email with phpmailer

you just change path include

and change parameters

```
function send_email($to, $subject, $message, $html = TRUE)
{
    require_once APPPATH .'libraries/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail                   = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPDebug        = 0;
    $mail->Debugoutput      = 'html';

    $mail->Host             = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth         = true;
    $mail->Username         = 'email@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password         = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure       = 'tls';
    $mail->Port             = 587;

    $mail->isHTML($html);
    $mail->charSet          = 'UTF-8';


    $from = 'domain@gmail.com';

    $mail->setFrom($from, 'no-reply');
    $mail->addAddress($to, 'Information');

    $mail->Subject          = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
    $mail->Body             = $message;
    $mail->AltBody          = '';

    if($mail->send())
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

OR sample : [This example shows sending a message using PHP's mail() function](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps)

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I don't use gmail smtp, I'm using Godaddy hosting and their email servers.

Comment: yes , you change parameters phpmailer ( host , SMTPSecure , port , username , password ... )

Comment: My code already a working code so I need some ideas about why I can not send email on the same domain address.

Comment: set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` Enable verbose debug output

Comment: answer me update . click to link sample mail() with phpmailer

Comment: question run script XAMPP  or   WAMP ?

Comment: I tried soultion on your updated link, it says mail sends and still not receiving.