# PHPMailer & CharSet 'utf-8' ignore fetched data in utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, phpmailer

I'm fetching data from a mysql table (collation 'utf8_unicode_ci') and dynamically fill an email template and send the mail via PHPMailer. As of right now the special characters in the data fetched are displayed correctly. The special characters in the plain text in the mail.html are not.

As per the PHPMailer docs ... when adding $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

then the special characters in the plain text in the mail.html are displayed correctly ... but the fetched data from the database not anymore.

What am I missing?

Update:

```
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8mb4');
```

... just before the select statement solved the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42248356/4232159

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Comment: `$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';` its true .

Comment: Yes ... but as described ... when I do this the special characters from my sql query are not displayed correct anymore.

Comment: plz screenshot output .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$mail->CharSet = 'utf8_unicode_ci';` is just wrong - that's a MySQL collation, not a character set. `$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';` is correct for the email side of things, but you need to make sure that the data you're getting back from the database is actually in UTF-8 - there is plenty of documentation on how to do that, for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly). Also bear in mind that MySQL's standard UTF-8 charset is not complete; if you want to support things like emoji, you need to use its [`utf8mb4` charset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Comment: Thanks for the hint Synchro. So with mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8mb4'); just before the select statement everything is displayed correctly. Many thanks